# Align Buttons to Bottom of Xamarin.Forms Grid without ListView Spacer

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, layout

I am working on a simple details screen that gives some list item details and the option to delete the item.  It has a `StackLayout` to display item details and two `Button`s to navigate back or to delete.

I have managed to align the two `Button`s along the bottom of their parent `Grid` by using an empty `ListView` as a vertical spacer (note the `RowDefinition.Height` for the `ListView`'s `Grid.Row` is set to `*`):

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding TextLabel}" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="Small" />
        <Label Text="{Binding DescriptionLabel}" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Small" />
    </StackLayout>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button
            Text="{Binding BackButton}"
            Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
        <Button
            Grid.Column="1"
            Text="{Binding DeleteButton}"
            Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

While this works, it feels like an abuse of the `ListView`.  Ideally I would like to remove `<ListView Grid.Row="1" />` entirely, and have the `StackLayout` in the first row expand as much as it can so that it shoves the `Button` `Grid` in the last row all the way to the bottom of the screen.  I suppose I would be fine with the `Button` `Grid` expanding upwards as well, if it is not possible to have the `StackLayout` expand.

So short and sweet, how can I get rid of the phony `ListView` spacer and still have my `Button`s at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: I can't reproduce, after removing the ListView the buttons are still in the bottom

Comment: Using XF v4.2.0.  With respect to the entire page, the above `Grid` is the content of a `ContentView`, itself the content of another `ContentView`, which is the sole occupant of a padded `StackLayout`, which is finally the content of a `ContentPage`.  Hoping none of that matters, and it may well simply be the version of XF I have is just buggy (but currently stuck with it :-/ ).

Comment: Simply make the first row `Height="*"`?

Comment: I did try that, but it didn't work for me.  Was that effective in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the code like below. I tested with no listview.

**Change:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button
        Text="{Binding BackButton}"
        Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
    <Button
        Grid.Column="1"
        Text="{Binding DeleteButton}"
        Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

**To:**

```
 <StackLayout
        Grid.Row="1"
        Orientation="Horizontal"
        VerticalOptions="End">
        <Button HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  Text="{Binding BackButton}" Command="{Binding BackCommand}" />
        <Button HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Text="{Binding DeleteButton}" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This does not work either.  I am beginning to wonder if this is just a bug in my current version of XF (4.2.0).

Comment: I checked on the XF4.2. Code still works. Check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/LiulfHd

Comment: Finally circling back around to this.  I found that your solution works if used directly within the `ContentPage` -- in my `ContentPage`, I replaced the `ContentView` with the contents of that `ContentView`, i.e. the above `Grid`.

Comment: Additionally, I was able to make the original `ContentPage`/`ContentView` setup work by setting `VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"` on the `ContentView`.